# pyside / pyqt: Getting values from dynamically created qlineedits on button clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qlineedit

I have a program that creates a number of qlineedits and buttons depending on the users input:

[image: screenshot of GUI]

On the image above 4 lines have been added with a button after the grayed out "Next" button was clicked. Now I want to get the input from the user into a function when the corresponding button is clicked (Click "Create Shot 1! --> goto a function with "exShot1" passed as an argument).

The thing is I have no idea how to get the names of each qline and button when they are created in a loop. I guess I could create unique variables in the loop but that doesn't feel right. I have tried using `setObjectName` but I can't figure out how I can use that to call the text. I also made an unsuccessful attempt with Lamdba (which I have a feeling might be the right way to go somehow)  I believe it's a combination of having to fetch the name and tracking when the user input is changed.

I have experimented with `textChanged` and I got it to work on the last entry of the loop but not for the other qlines and buttons)

Relevant code:

```
while i <= int(seqNum):
    #create each widget
    self.createShotBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Create Shot %s!" %str(self.shotNumberLst[i-1]))
    self.labelName = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    self.labelName.setText("Enter Name Of Shot %s!" %str(self.shotNumberLst[i-1]))
    self.shotName = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
    self.shotName.setObjectName("shot"+str(i))

    #add widget to layout
    self.grid.addWidget(self.labelName, 11+shotjump,0)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.shotName,11+shotjump,1)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.createShotBtn, 11+shotjump,2)

    #Press button that makes magic happen
    self.createShotBtn.clicked.connect(???)

    i += 1
```

edit: It would also be fine if the user entered input on all the lines and just pressed one button that passed all those inputs as a list or dict (there will be more lines added per "shot")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that on each run through the values of `self.createShotBtn`, `self.labelName` and `self.shotName` are being overridden.

So on the last run through, they are fixed, but only for the last iteration.

Instead, you want to use a locally scoped variable in the loop, and potentially store it in an array for later use.

This code should come close to what you need, but I can see where `self.shotNumberLst` (which returns a number?) and `shotjump` (which is an offest, or equal to to `i`) are declared.

```
self.shots = []
for i in range(seqNum): # Changed while to for, so you don't need to increment
    #create each widget
    createShotBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Create Shot %s!" %str(self.shotNumberLst[i-1]))
    labelName = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    labelName.setText("Enter Name Of Shot %s!" %str(self.shotNumberLst[i-1]))
    shotName = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

    self.shots.append({"button":createShotBtn,
                       "name":shotName)) # Store for later if needed.

    #add widget to layout
    self.grid.addWidget(labelName, 11+shotjump,0)
    self.grid.addWidget(shotName,11+shotjump,1)
    self.grid.addWidget(createShotBtn, 11+shotjump,2)

    #Press button that makes magic happen
    createShotBtn.clicked.connect(self.createShot(i))

#elsewhere
def createShot(self,index):
    print self.shots[index]["name"].text
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
while i <= int(seqNum):

    #create each widget
    createShotBtn = "ShotBtn"+str(i)
    self.createShotBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Create Shot %s!" %str(self.shotNumberLst[i-1]))

    labelName = "labName"+str(i)
    self.labelName = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    self.labelName.setText("Enter Name Of Shot %s!" %str(self.shotNumberLst[i-1]))

    shotName = "shtName"+str(i)
    self.shotName = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)


    #add widget to layout
    self.grid.addWidget(self.labelName, 11+shotjump,0)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.shotName,11+shotjump,1)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.createShotBtn, 11+shotjump,2)

    #Press button that makes magic happen
    self.createShotBtn.clicked.connect(self.printText)

    i += 1

def printText(self):
    print(self.shotName.text())
```

This will print the text when you push the button on the same line.